# How to entegrate existing .m file into the simulink .mdl file

Tags: matlab, model, simulink, robotics

I'm using robotic toolbox by Peter Corke in Matlab .  I have .m file for puma560 robot (it is for robot trajectory. The robot follows given path). When I try to use  for ex.  "sl_ctorque"  simulink file which is in robotic toolbox(it is about computed torque method) , I couldn't entegrate my .m file into the simulink file. My .m file is given below. So if anyone know how to do this idea, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

```
clear;clc; 
mdl_puma560    %to create puma robot

for type=1:3  % main for loop. It turns 3 times. At first, it sets the path
    %           to x-y plane and draw the robot, at second for y-z plane
    %           and then for x-z plane

  if type==1 

% The path of robot for x-y plane    
path=[0 0 1;0 0 0;0 2 0 ;0.5 1 0 ;1 2 0;1 0 0;1.5 0 1;1.5 0 0;
      1.5 2 0;2.2 2 0;2.5 1.6 0;2.5 0.4 0;2.2 0 0;1.5 0 0;0 0 1];


 elseif type==2   

% Same thing as first part    
path=[-0.5 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 1;0 -0.5 0.5;0 -1 1;0 -1 0;-0.5 -1.2 0;0 -1.2 0;
    0 -1.2 1;0 -1.7 1;0 -2 0.7;0 -2 0.3;0 -1.7 0;0 -1.2 0];


 elseif type==3

 % Same thing as first and second part     
path=[0 -0.5 0;0 0 0;0 0 1;0.5 0 0.5;1 0 1;1 0 0;1.3 -0.5 0;1.3 0 0;
    1.3 0 1;1.7 0 1;2 0 0.7;2 0 0.3;1.7 0 0;1.3 0 0];


  end



% I created a trajectory

p=mstraj(path, [15 15 15], [], [1 0 1], 0.02 , 0.2);

% [15 15 15] means the maximum speed in x,y,z directions.
% [1 0 1] means the initial coordinates
% 0.02 means acceleration time
% 0.2 means smoothness of robot


numrows(p)*0.2;    % 200 ms sample interval
Tp=transl(0.1*p);  % Scale factor of robot
Tp=homtrans( transl(0.4,0,0),Tp);  % Origin of the letter
q=p560.ikine6s(Tp);   % The inverse kinematic


for i=1:length(q)
% q matrix has 280 rows and 6 columns. So this for loop turns 280 times
% At every turns , it plots one part of movement. q(1,:), q(2,:), ...  

    p560.plot(q(i,:))


end

end
```

Comment: As mentioned to you before, nobody here will know about the robotics toolbox, it's a very "niche" toolbox that is not part of the standard MATLAB release, and I'd never heard of it until I read your post.

Comment: @am304 My post doesn't about only robotic toolbox , this toolbox is only example.  If you know how can I entegrate any .m file to the any .mdl file , pls help me.

Comment: the way it was asked, it sounded as it was specific to the robotics toolbox. See NKN's answer for integrate MATLAB functions in Simulink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your m file as a function and then use the **MATLAB Function Block**.
The MATLAB Function block allows you to add MATLAB® functions to Simulink® models for deployment to desktop and embedded processors. This capability is useful for coding algorithms that are better stated in the textual language of the MATLAB software than in the graphical language of the Simulink product.

[image]

Then you can open the block as paste your function:

[image]

to see an example check out [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/creating-an-example-model-that-uses-a-matlab-function-block.html).